# Python incrementally set a variable to equal another variable

Tags: python, loops, iteration, increment

I am attempting to set the value of a variable to incrementally equal that of another variable based on the iteration of the loop I am on.

I have the following code:

```
no_keywords=3

cat_0='Alpha'
cat_1='Bravo'
cat_2='Charlie'
cat_3='Delta'

for _ in range(no_keywords):

  keyword1 = exec(f'cat_{_}')
  
  print(keyword1)
```

However the printed value just returns a NoneType object. I would like the value of Keyword1 to take on the value of the cat_ variable based on the iteration of loop I am on.

Please can somebody help in explaining in what I am doing wrong and help me recitfy?

Thanks,

D

Comment: Don't do that. Use a list.

Comment: BTW, `no_keywords` should be `4`.

Comment: Use `eval()`, not `exec()`.

Comment: @Barmar "Don't do that. Use a list" and "Use eval(), not exec()" seem like contradictory pieces of advice.

Comment: @khelwood The first is a recommendation, the second is how to fix his code.

Comment: @Barmar And if they actually said that, they would not be contradictory.

Comment: @khelwood It was stream of consciousness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
no_keywords = 3

cat_0 = 'Alpha'
cat_1 = 'Bravo'
cat_2 = 'Charlie'
cat_3 = 'Delta'

for _ in range(no_keywords):
    keyword1 = None

    exec(f'keyword1 = cat_{_}')

    print(keyword1)
```

Seems like `exec` does not return a value, but you can set your variable within the command passed to it.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly :)

Comment: You can also use `eval()` to return the value of an expression.